# Day of week display for windows 7 gone?

Tags: windows-7, date-format

I can no longer see the day of the week by hovering over the date on my Dell latitude using windows 7. Going to  Control panel/ region & Language  / Formats +/- Additional settings doesn't give a dddd option.

Answer (score 1):

#### The "Additional settings" dialog doesn't give a `dddd` option.

This option is set on the "Customize Format" dialog "Date" tab:

- Goto "Control panel" > "Region & Language"
- Click the "Formats" tab
- Click "Additional settings"

[image]

- Click the "Date" tab
- Enter dddd in the "Long date" field
- Press "OK"
- Press "OK" again on the next dialog.

[image]

Comment: Yes that was helpful. I had been expecting to have dddd in a drop down menu in the additional settings (which it is not) but as you point out  in additional settings you can type in dddd

Comment: @DavidPostill: You don't need to keep telling users to accept your answers.